# Consume OData service with Visual Studio 2017 and C#

Tags: c#, odata

I want to consume an existing OData service in C# with Visual Studio 2017.

OData v4 client code generator is not compatible with VS2017.

I can't find examples without this extension?

Thanks for all

Comment: you say: "OData v4 client code generator is not compatible with VS2017." Is it really not compatible? How did you come to this conclusion? Maybe you should ask another question about how this can be solved.

Comment: @jps It is really not compatible

Comment: An issue is opened at https://github.com/OData/lab/issues/51. There are some unofficial forks, where VS2017 support has been implemented.

Comment: seem like a legitimate question. It's not working for me either

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981604/how-to-update-odata-wcf-in-visual-studio-2017/48470007 -- the Marketplace tool has been updated to support VS 2017.