# How to update OData WCF in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2017

Trying to update Service Reference in an existing project, I got an error that says,

> The specified OData API cannot be updated because OData APIs are now only supported with Connected Services.

[image]

The aka link (http://aka.ms/odatavsclientguidance) leads to http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#OData-Client-Code-Generation-Tool.

[image]

There is no instruction for VS 2017.

The instruction below leads me to the **OData Connected Serve** VS extension. 
(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=laylaliu.ODataConnectedService)
[image]

And it appears that extension cannot be installed in VS 2017.
[image]

Scroll to the bottom of the extension description page, we will see all the questions about its VS 2017 version.

[image]

So the question: is that OData extension the only to update OData Service in VS 2017? What walk around do we have?

Comment: Same problem here : no solution yet, if you don't have a vs 2015 somewhere, seems that you're stuck until a 2017 version is released...

Comment: Thanks. I decided to install VS 2015 now.

Answer (score 1):

The official [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=laylaliu.ODataConnectedService) code generation tool, which you refer to in your post, now supports Visual Studio 2017.

One notable difference from how one would normally go about setting up OData references is that where one would previously use Visual Studio's "Add Service Reference" directly to generate the relevant code, installing the tool adds a "Add Connected Service" instead.

See also the discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/OData/lab/issues/51).

Answer (score 0):

In your Solution Explorer, right click on References, Add Connected Service then select Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider, you'll get a Wizard-like window to add a Service Reference just like in VS2015.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Images at https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe6dc.jpg